# How to select the text from the first <a> tag from each <td> element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a table of Events, and I need to get the event name from each.

```
var event_names = new Array();  // Initialise to avoid errors
$('td.event_name a', '#the-list').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).text());
    event_names.push($(this).text());
});
```

However, this fails because there is more than one `<a>` tag within the `td.event_name`, and I only need the first.

I've tried this also, but I'm getting the error `$(this).$... is not a function`.

```
var event_names = new Array();  // Initialise to avoid errors
$('td.event_name', '#the-list').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).$('a:first').text());
    event_names.push($(this).$('a:first').text());
});
```

Does anybody know how I could get round this?

Here is some source, for just one of the `<td>` elements. I cannot see any obvioius selectors to work off of in this code (and I cannot change it).

```
<td class="event_name column-event_name">
    <label><strong><a title="Edit this event" href="admin.php?page=dd-options-edit-event&amp;event=126" class="edit">
        Test Event
    </a></strong></label>
    <img style="display: none; margin-left: 10px;" src="http://test.dynedrewett.com/wp-admin/images/wpspin_light.gif" alt="" class="waiting">
    <div class="row-actions">
        <span class="edit"><a title="Edit this event" href="admin.php?page=dd-options-edit-event&amp;event=126" class="edit">Edit</a> | </span>
        <span class="inline hide-if-no-js"><a title="Quick edit this event" href="#" class="editinline">Quick Edit</a> | </span>
        <span class="copy"><a title="Copy this event" href="#" class="single-copy">Copy</a> | </span>
        <span class="delete"><a title="Delete this event" href="#" class="single-delete">Delete</a> | </span>
        <span class="open"><a target="_blank" title="Close this event" href="#" class="single-switch-state">Close</a> | </span>
        <span class="view"><a target="_blank" title="View this event" href="http://test.dynedrewett.com/events/?e=126" class="single-view">View</a> | </span>
        <span class="invitations"><a title="Manage invitations to this event" href="http://test.dynedrewett.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=dd-options-event-invitations&amp;event=126" class="single-view">Invitations</a></span>
    </div>
</td>
```

Comment: _"$... is not a function"_ Is jQuery being included successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `:first` selector, like this:

```
$('td.event_name a:first', '#the-list').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).text());
    event_names.push($(this).text());
});
```

For reference, your second attempt is getting `$(this).$ is not a function` due to a syntax error, it should look like either of these:

```
console.log($('a:first', this).text());
console.log($(this).find('a:first').text());
```

Comment: Are you sure this works? See http://jsfiddle.net/Yc3ps/ Only prints one 1 to the console.

Comment: You first example only prints the first `<a>` text value from the first `<td>`, but your bottom two work just fine. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('td.event_name a:first');
```

or

```
$('td.event_name', '#the-list').each(function(){
    console.log( $(this).find('a:first') );
});
```

or

```
$('td.event_name', '#the-list').each(function(){
    console.log( $(this).children('a:first') );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
$('td.event_name').each(function(i, td) {
     console.log($(td).find('a:first').text());
});
```

See it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Yc3ps/1/).

Answer (score 1):

what about :

```
var event_names = new Array();  // Initialise to avoid errors
$('td.event_name').each(function(){
  console.log($(this).find('a').first().text());
  event_names.push($(this).find('a').first().text());
});
```